# Qt: Making disabled QAction selectable so the user can toggle it back to enabled

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, contextmenu

I have a QTreeView and for the items of this tree view, I have implemented a toggle functionality. The user right clicks an item and the context menu shows up, if the user selects toggle, it should toggle the status of the item between enabled and disabled.

I have no problems disabling the item. However, once disabled, even though I set it selectable, the item is still not selectable so the user has no chance of toggling the item back to enabled. Below is how I am currently trying. Any help would be appreciated.

```
QAction* toggleItem = new QAction("Toggle", &menu);
connect(toggleItem, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(toggle_item()));

...

void MyClass::toggle_item() {

    bool currentItemStatus = m_selectedItem->isVisible();
    m_selectedItem->setEnabled(!currentItemStatus);
    m_selectedItem->setSelectable(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of a disabled item is exact: it means that the item **cannot be interacted with**.

If you intend interaction with the item, you **must not** disable it - that's all. Use another visual indication, perhaps using the foreground and/or background roles.

Comment: While I was waiting for an answer, I actually went with editing foreground and background roles as you suggested. However, I still wanted to ask this because right now it's just a few more lines of code; being able to disable an item while still having a way of selecting it would be shorter, so I wanted to ask. It looks like I'm going as you suggested. Thank you.